# Menu displaying as a list

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm making a new theme and the menu is displaying as a list, with items, and I don't want that. [Here you have a link to the site](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/shugar).

This is my css code

```
.links {
    margin-left:250px;
list-style:none;   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which you don't want

Comment: there is no selector .links

Comment: .menu should have list-style: none,
there is no class name **.links**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
list-style: none;
```

to **.menu** class name specified element, not on **.links** ( which is not even exists ).

Comment: I see you added it to: #menucontainer, find .menu class name in your css file and add ``list-style: none;`` to it

Comment: write it to your style.css file: ``#menucontainer ul { list-style: none; }`` :)

Comment: Nevermind, I did it, thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

list-style:none; is to be applied to the ul, not the li tag.